# Import cvs to a table with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, csv

There is a 2 column MySQL database with a foreign key set (primary key is the foreign key). My question is, how can I import a csv file in to the database. I tried but only the first row gets insert.

sql:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/uploadData.csv' INTO TABLE mitems
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@itemCategory, items);
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Can you give us some more informations? CVS example, Tool or Script, SQL Table etc.?

Comment: @schnawel007 thanks. The cvs goes as `"furniture","Dark Red Chair"` and next line `"kitchen","Ladel"` and so on.... I use the import button in phpMyAdmin.